# How can I join all the futures in a vector without cancelling on failure like join_all does?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await

I've got a `Vec` of futures created from calling an `async` function. After adding all the futures to the vector, I'd like to wait on the whole set, getting either a list of results, or a callback for each one that finishes.

I could simply loop or iterate over the vector of futures and call `.await` on each future and that would allow me to handle errors correctly and not have [`futures::future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) cancel the others, but I'm sure there's a more idiomatic way to accomplish this task.

I also want to be able to handle the futures as they complete so if I get enough information from the first few, I can cancel the remaining incomplete futures and not wait for them and discard their results, error or not. This would not be possible if I iterated over the vector in order.

What I'm looking for is a callback (closure, etc) that lets me accumulate the results as they come in so that I can handle errors appropriately or cancel the remainder of the futures (from within the callback) if I determine I don't need the rest of them.

I can tell that's asking for a headache from the borrow checker: trying to modify a future in a `Vec` in a callback from the async engine.

There's a number of Stack Overflow questions and Reddit posts that explain how `join_all` joins on a list of futures but cancels the rest if one fails, and how async engines may spawn threads or they may not or they're bad design if they do.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: There's no error. I didn't supply a code sample because I don't have one yet. I don't know how to solve this problem, so that's why I'm asking. I am not asking for 'how to fix an error', I'm asking how to approach the problem since I can't find any tools that seem to do what I want.

Comment: That suggests that you are still on the research phase. The other problem is that it is unclear which `join_all` you speak of. For what it's worth, the `join_all` I found is the one in the `futures` crate, but since [`future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) is agnostic to the future's item, it won't cancel existing futures if one of them yields an error.

Comment: *I didn't supply a code sample because I don't have one yet.* vs *I've got a `Vec` of futures created from calling an `async` function* — the latter suggests that you've got code that you've chosen to not share.

Comment: @E_net4willhelpyouout An [older version of `future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) canceled the other futures on failure.

Comment: perhaps I was reading old documentation.

Comment: `the latter suggests that you've got code that you've chosen to not share` So... I have a program yes, but it doesn't yet do what I'm trying to do because I don't know how. It did not occur to me that that code might be useful in answering the question because it doesn't exhibit any problem. I'm planning on trying something new, so I was asking about the new thing. With all that, somebody was able to answer apparently.

Comment: actually to be more specific, I have a program that doesn't use futures at all, and I am PLANNING on having a vector of futures.

Comment: Shepmaster: `It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a minimal reproducible example` Code is not required to ask a question on Stack Overflow. `That suggests that you are still on the research phase.` Not being on the "research phase" is also not a requirement to post to Stack Overflow.  This sort of attitude is why SO is declining. Please be more welcoming to posters in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`futures::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/future/fn.select_all.html):

```
use futures::future; // 0.3.4

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>;
type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

async fn might_fail(fails: bool) -> Result<i32> {
    if fails {
        Ok(42)
    } else {
        Err("boom".into())
    }
}

async fn many() -> Result<i32> {
    let raw_futs = vec![might_fail(true), might_fail(false), might_fail(true)];
    let unpin_futs: Vec<_> = raw_futs.into_iter().map(Box::pin).collect();
    let mut futs = unpin_futs;

    let mut sum = 0;

    while !futs.is_empty() {
        match future::select_all(futs).await {
            (Ok(val), _index, remaining) => {
                sum += val;
                futs = remaining;
            }
            (Err(_e), _index, remaining) => {
                // Ignoring all errors
                futs = remaining;
            }
        }

        if sum > 42 {
            // Early exit
            return Ok(sum);
        }
    }

    Ok(sum)
}
```

This will poll all the futures in the collection, returning the first one that is not pending, its index, and the remaining pending or unpolled futures. You can then match on the `Result` and handle the success or failure case.

Call `select_all` inside of a loop. This gives you the ability to exit early from the function. When you exit, the `futs` vector is dropped and dropping a future cancels it.

Comment: This isn't necessary now, since `join_all` since futures `0.3` won't fail, and meets OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments by @kmdreko, @John Kugelman and @e-net4-the-comment-flagger, use join_all from the futures crate version 0.3.   The join_all in futures version 0.2 has the cancel behavior described in the question, but join_all in futures crate version 0.3 does not.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick/hacky solution without having to mess with `select_all`. You can use `join_all`, but instead of returning `Result<T>` return `Result<Result<T>>` - always returning `Ok` for the top-level result

Answer (score -3):

Or you can use [join_all](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.join_all.html)

The example from the documentation:

```rust
use futures::future::join_all;

async fn foo(i: u32) -> u32 { i }

let futures = vec![foo(1), foo(2), foo(3)];

assert_eq!(join_all(futures).await, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: The original question specifically complains about `join_all` saying that it stops at the first error. This is untrue in the current version of the function (and even when posted judging by the comments), but you should at least remark that the premise is not true.