# How to execute multiple async functions at once and get the results?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I have tried Tokio tasks, but there are no working examples to execute multiple tasks at once. What is wrong with this code?

```rust
fn main() {
    block_on(speak());
}

async fn speak() {
    let hold = vec![say(), greet()];
    let results = join_all(hold).await;
}

async fn say() {
    println!("hello");
}

async fn greet() {
    println!("world");
}
```

here is the compiler output

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> sync\src\main.rs:14:27
   |
14 |     let hold = vec![say(),greet()];
   |                           ^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found a different opaque type
...
23 | async fn greet(){
   |                 - the `Output` of this `async fn`'s found opaque type
   |
   = note:     expected type `impl core::future::future::Future` (opaque type at <sync\src\main.rs:19:15>)
           found opaque type `impl core::future::future::Future` (opaque type at <sync\src\main.rs:23:17>)
   = note: distinct uses of `impl Trait` result in different opaque types
```

Comment: Why not use the [`join!`](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.5/futures_util/macro.join.html) macro?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

For two futures, like you have, use [`future::join`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.join.html)

```
use futures::{executor, future}; // 0.3.5

async fn speak() {
    let (_s, _g) = future::join(say(), greet()).await;
}
```

There are variants for three, four, and five input futures: [`join3`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.join3.html), [`join4`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.join4.html), [`join5`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.join5.html).

There is also [`try_join`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.try_join.html) (and [`try_join3`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.try_join3.html), [`try_join4`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.try_join4.html), [`try_join5`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.try_join5.html)) for when your future returns a `Result`.

The macro [`join`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/macro.join.html) is another way to handle a static number of futures to join.

If you need to support a dynamic number of futures, you can use [`future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) (or [`try_join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.try_join_all.html)), but you have to have a vector of all one kind. This is easiest via [`FutureExt::boxed`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.boxed) (or [`FutureExt::boxed_local`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.boxed_local)):

```
use futures::{executor, future, FutureExt}; // 0.3.5

async fn speak() {
    let futures = vec![say().boxed(), greet().boxed()];
    let _results = future::join_all(futures).await;
}
```

Note that this code can run the futures concurrently but will not run them in parallel. For parallel execution, you need to introduce some kind of tasks.

See also:

- [How can I join all the futures in a vector without cancelling on failure like join_all does?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61481079/155423)
- [Join futures with limited concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43247212/155423)
- [How can I perform parallel asynchronous HTTP GET requests with reqwest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51044467/155423)
- [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27957103/155423)
- [What is the purpose of async/await in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52835725/155423)
- [What is the difference between concurrency and parallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050222/155423)

Comment: Please mark the accepted answer to this question. This answer helped me when I had the same question.

Comment: Is boxed still required? It doesn't seems like it from the docs.
https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.30/futures/future/fn.join_all.html